# App engine windows error - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I am using google app engine with Python. When I launch the app engine application I get a prompt message that error occurred and suggest me to see the log file. I have checked the log file and found the following message

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\platform\\bundledpython;
 C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\platform\\bundledpython\\Lib\\site-packages;
 C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\platform\\gsutil\\third_party\\oauth2client\\oauth2client/Google'
```

I have recently setup some environment variable and these paths seem valid to me apart from the last path which i cannot see in any of my env variables.

I have also tried to uninstall the Google Cloud SDK and App Engine SDK but I am still getting the same error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have removed all the app engine install directory path from the environment variable and re-install the app engine sdk. I am no longer getting the The system cannot find the path specified error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I get this error on windows when the full path of any file gets too long